# CSS image overlay with color and transparency

Tags: html, image, css

I am trying to figure out if I can add an overlay to an image like a tint and change the opacity without adding background color. I had no luck so I thought I would ask here.
***I would like to make it red with that opacity.*** here is what I have so far.

I made an image to overlay it if I have to called overlay.png but don't know  if its necessary.

```
img.highlighted {
   opacity:0.4;
}
```

Basically I want to do this but reverse, for image to tint when hovered not to take the tint away when hovered.
check it out here
http://jsbin.com/igahay/3011/edit

Comment: If you try it in Photoshop you'll see it won't work there either, simply because the premise in wrong. Overlaying a semi-transparent colored mask on top of a colored base image just gives ugly results, not a recolored result.

Comment: how about overlaying it with another image, I guess I can deal with that

Comment: Can you use CSS3, or must be a fully cross-browser solution?

Comment: Check this: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### CSS Filter Effects

<sup>It's not [fully cross-browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=filter) solution, but must work well in 
 most modern browser.</sup>

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
<style>
    img:hover {
        /* Ch 23+, Saf 6.0+, BB 10.0+ */
        -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) saturate(3.3) grayscale(50%);
        /* FF 35+ */
        filter: hue-rotate(240deg) saturate(3.3) grayscale(50%);
    }
</style>
```

**EXTERNAL DEMO PLAYGROUND**

- [CSS Filter Effects](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html)

**IN-HOUSE DEMO SNIPPET** *(source:[simpl.info](http://simpl.info/cssfilters/))*

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(5px)
}

.grayscale {
  filter: grayscale(1)
}

.saturate {
  filter: saturate(5)
}

.sepia {
  filter: sepia(1)
}

.multi {
  filter: blur(4px) invert(1) opacity(0.5)
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <h1><a href="https://simpl.info/cssfilters/" title="simpl.info home page">simpl.info</a> CSS filters</h1>

  <img src="https://simpl.info/cssfilters/balham.jpg" alt="No filter: Balham High Road and a rainbow" />
  <img class="blur" src="https://simpl.info/cssfilters/balham.jpg" alt="Blur filter: Balham High Road and a rainbow" />
  <img class="grayscale" src="https://simpl.info/cssfilters/balham.jpg" alt="Grayscale filter: Balham High Road and a rainbow" />
  <img class="saturate" src="https://simpl.info/cssfilters/balham.jpg" alt="Saturate filter: Balham High Road and a rainbow" />
  <img class="sepia" src="https://simpl.info/cssfilters/balham.jpg" alt="Sepia filter: Balham High Road and a rainbow" />
  <img class="multi" src="https://simpl.info/cssfilters/balham.jpg" alt="Blur, invert and opacity filters: Balham High Road and a rainbow" />

  <p><a href="https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/gh-pages/cssfilters" title="View source for this page on GitHub" id="viewSource">View source on GitHub</a></p>

</div>
```

**NOTES**

- This property is significantly different from and incompatible with Microsoft's [older "filter" property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- **Edge**, element or it's parent can't have negative z-index (see [bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9318580/))
- **IE** use old school way ([link](https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/)) <sup>*thanks @Costa*</sup>

**RESOURCES**:

- [Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/) [w3.org] <kbd>w3 ref</kbd>
- [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) [developer.mozilla.org] <kbd>doc</kbd>
- [Chrome platform status](http://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5822463824887808): [chromestatus.com] <kbd>official</kbd> <kbd>status</kbd>
- [Browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=filter) [caniuse.com] <kbd>ref</kbd>
- [Say Hello to Webkit Filters](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/say-hello-to-css3-filters) [tutsplus.com] <kbd>info</kbd>
- [Understanding CSS Filters Effect](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/) [html5rocks.com] <kbd>doc</kbd>

Comment: CSS filters don't work in IE is there a way to overlay a filter pre-made in photoshop? Like a transparent white png to white wash.

Comment: Never mind, here's the old school way: https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/

Answer (score 14):

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgirish/6ELSF/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="image-holder">
    <img src="http://codemancers.com/img/who-we-are-bg.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.image-holder {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.image-holder:after {
    content:'';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
.image-holder:hover:after {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make the reverse of what you showed consider doing this:

```
.tint:hover:before {
    background: rgba(0,0,250, 0.5);

  }

  .t2:before {
    background: none;
  }
```

and look at the effect on the 2nd picture.

Is it supposed to look like [this](http://jsbin.com/igahay/3012/edit)?

Comment: wait wut? I think you wrote the comment on the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

something like this? http://codepen.io/Nunotmp/pen/wKjvB

You can add an empty `div` and use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given a try to **Webkit Filters?**

You can manipulate not only opacity, but colour, brightness, luminosity and other properties: