# How to place a color cover on top of an image in CSS

Tags: css, hover

I want to be able to cover an image with blue colour when I hover on top of it.

How could I implement this with pure CSS?

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <h1>Some title here</h1>
  <img src="the_image.png" height: "100px", width: "100px">
  <p>Some text here...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don´t want to use a background image and want to have a full browser support you can do it this way.
And you can use opacity.

http://jsfiddle.net/charly3176/Sf97g/

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <h1>Some title here</h1>
    <div class="background">
        <img src="the_image.png">
    </div>

  <p>Some text here...</p>
</div>


.background {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: blue;
}

img:hover {
    opacity:.3;
}
```

Comment: That was exactly the effect i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I dunno exactly what you're going for, but [here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6AD8x/1/)

```
#cat {
    background: url(http://www.funnycatsite.com/pictures/Do_Not_Turn_The_Water_On.jpg);
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
#cat:hover {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CSS3, try with `CSS:filter` ans specially `-webkit-filter`
<sup>(It's not a fully cross-browser solution... yet!)</sup>

```
   img:hover {
      -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) saturate(3.3); 
   }
```

Here you have a few online demos:

- [CSS Filter Effects](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html)
- [Say Hello to Webkit Filters](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/say-hello-to-css3-filters)
- [More on
  google...](https://www.google.es/search?q=-webkit-filter&oq=-webkit-filter&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i62l3.466j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22-webkit-filter%22&oq=%22-webkit-filter%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i19j0i30i19l3.700650.702409.1.702628.3.3.0.0.0.0.142.404.0j3.3.0....0.0..1c.1.20.psy-ab.yT36YE9y9Kg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099,d.bGE,pv.xjs.s.en_US.c75bKy5EQ0A.O&fp=35f736e541b336c7&biw=1679&bih=937)

Hope it's help.. or at least point you in the right direction.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721960/css-image-overlay-with-color-and-transparency)