# Bring carousel caption on top of the overlay

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Bootstrap carousel:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-overlay"></div>

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1600/600" /></a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Meow</h3>
        <p>Just Kitten Around</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1600/600" /></a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Meow</h3>
        <p>Just Kitten Around</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1600/600" /></a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Meow</h3>
        <p>Just Kitten Around</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.carousel-overlay{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

I want the caption and arrow buttons to be on the top the overlay like the carousel indicators. I tried using z-index, but it is not working.

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bM32G/39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the captions and arrow buttons on top of the overlay with z-index in this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1xu2fpc8/

I used some `!important` for simplicity, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: Like i said z-index is not working for me. Nothing happens

Comment: Did you take a look at the jsfiddle I linked? I don't know if I'm misunderstanding you, but in the jsfiddle all the elements you wanted above the overlay are above the overlay.

Comment: Yeah i looked at it and That's what I need. But it's not working for me :(

Comment: Hmm alright. Is it possible for you to put the CSS you added to the slider in your JSFiddle, so I can see what else styling there is that might interfere with z-index?

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the content of the carousel you need to refer to, in this case, `img`. Add the following code to your CSS:

```
img{
 -webkit-filter: sepia(90%) hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

Remove or comment out the following line in your HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-overlay"></div>
```

You can also look into the following posts:

1. [Tint image using CSS without overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546499/tint-image-using-css-without-overlay)
2. [CSS image overlay with color and transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721960/css-image-overlay-with-color-and-transparency)

Comment: If I remove z-index, the overlay is not visible at all.

Comment: @Nivedita I've updated my answer, please have a look and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since `z-index` is not working for you..

Try this

```
.item a img {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.carousel-control {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item .carousel-caption {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bM32G/43/)